# How to make my app to download in only in sdcard android?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-sdcard

I am new to android and going to launch an android app in google play .Since ,my app size is high I want my app should be download in the users sdcard when they download it.

What I have to do for this ? Is I have to give any permission in my manifest file ?

Could anyone suggest me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Comment: you can define using options given in above url posted by Mike M, where you wish your application to be installed (on internal or external storage), but downloading of your app is solely defined by google play application and it is most probably in the internal storage area.

Comment: That's a good point. I assumed they meant installation location.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Yes but that's how far his control goes, if Android decides to download to internal storage instead of external even though there's not enough space, there's nothing he can do about it. And if there is enough space, it's only temporary until installation (in the best case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Keep in mind though that not every device has an SD-card slot.

Comment: Thanks for your post.If I did not mention it ,where it will get downloaded

Comment: "If you do not declare this attribute, your application will be installed on the internal storage". Just read the documentation, I posted the link as the source. It's very clear and should answer any of your open questions regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"  put this in your manifest , or more information just go through with this link :
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Comment: link is not clickable